# Бесконечно вложеный массив

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы

Из запроса в БД нужно сформировать вложеный массив. 
Поля таблицы:
id,text,id_parent
[image: Структура массива]

Потуги решения:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        if($row->id_parent){
            $mas[$row->id_parent]['children'][$row->id]['id'] = $row->id;
            $mas[$row->id_parent]['children'][$row->id]['text'] = $row->text;
            $mas[$row->id_parent]['children'][$row->id]['id_parent'] = $row->id_parent;
        }else{
            $mas[$row->id]['id'] = $row->id;
            $mas[$row->id]['text'] = $row->text;
            $mas[$row->id]['id_parent'] = $row->id_parent;
        }
```

Comment: И? Вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Собственно как сформировать массив такого вида?

Comment: Вытаскивай данные и формируй, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: проблема в том, что формируя массив, я не знаю, в каком уровне вложености находится родительский

Comment: Приведи свои потуги решения. Плюс - я сомневаюсь что делать многомногоуровневый массив - такая хорошая идея. Вполне можно одно-двух мерным обойтись в 99%.

Comment: Добавил. У меня два варианта: Или многоуровневый массив, или бешеная рекусия. Нужно вывести дерево коментариев, у каждого из которых может быть дочерний коментарий

Comment: @Rikaz лучше рекурсией, но с ограниченным количеством вызовов. Лучше перестраховаться от зацикливания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function buildTree(array $data, $id = 'node_id', $parent = 'parent_id', $children = 'children')
{
    if (empty($id) || empty($parent) || empty($children)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
    }

    $tree = $refs = [];

    foreach ($data as &$node) {
        $refs[$node[$id]] = &$node;
        $node[$children] = [];

        if (null === ($node[$parent])) {
            $tree[$node[$id]] = &$node;
        } else {
            $refs[$node[$parent]][$children][$node[$id]] = &$node;
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function buildTreeArray($arItems, $section_id = 'Ид_родителя', $element_id = 'Ид') {
    $childs = array();
    if(!is_array($arItems) || empty($arItems)) {
        return array();
    }
    foreach($arItems as &$item) {
        if(!$item[$section_id]) {
            $item[$section_id] = 0;
        }
        $childs[$item[$section_id]][] = &$item;
    }
    unset($item);
    foreach($arItems as &$item) {
        if (isset($childs[$item[$element_id]])) {
            $item['childs'] = $childs[$item[$element_id]];
        }
    }
    return $childs[0];
}
```