# Генерация вложенного массива

Tags: php

Подскажите как лучше сгенерировать массива,вложенность составляет около 4-5 уровней.Стуктура в бд следующая.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле parent и определеяет родителя в которого вложен элемент.Parent-0 это корневой узел.Первым запросом я вытащу все корневые узлы,вторым уже все которые не равны 0.Интересует момент как сконструировать сам массив с такой вложенностью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама функция:

```
function buildTree(array $pages, $parent = 0)
{
    $branch = [];

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        if ($page['parent'] == $parent) {
            $children = buildTree($pages, $page['id_pages']);

            if ($children) {
                $page['children'] = $children;
            }

            $branch[] = $page;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
$pages = // SELECT pages
$tree  = buildTree($pages);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,очень полезная функция!

Answer (score 1):

```
   function buildTreeArray($arItems, $section_id = 'Ид_родителя', $element_id = 'Ид') {
    $childs = array();
    if(!is_array($arItems) || empty($arItems)) {
        return array();
    }
    foreach($arItems as &$item) {
        if(!$item[$section_id]) {
            $item[$section_id] = 0;
        }
        $childs[$item[$section_id]][] = &$item;
    }
    unset($item);
    foreach($arItems as &$item) {
        if (isset($childs[$item[$element_id]])) {
            $item['childs'] = & $childs[$item[$element_id]];
        }
    }
    return $childs[0];
}
```

Вытаскивать все данные нужно одним запросом

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/427432/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2/427440)

Comment: Ссылочку забыли — $item['childs'] = `&`$childs[$item[$element_id]];

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов, спасибо, поправил